# MacOS MySQL with Workbench - How many EER Diagrams can I have?

Tags: mysql, macos, schema, mysql-workbench

I am used to other DBMSs where there is only one schema which includes all EER links in one Diagram. It seems as if it is possible to have multiple EER Diagrams which combine together to form the schema. Is this correct ? If so does Workbench ensure that they are all consistent ? ie if a link relationship in one diagram is changed, does workbench automatically update other affected EER Diagrams ?

Comment: Dont worry Folk - I've found the answer to my question.

Comment: As many EER Diagrams as are needed may be created, thus making it possible to have nice, simple and clear diagrams for different parts of the whole schema - rather than having one, big, ugly and over complex diagram for the whole thing - To add a new EER Diagram there is an "Add Diagram" button on the MySQL Model tab - Right clicking on the icon for an existing EER Diagram enables one to rename the diagram, export it as a .pdf or delete the diagram